# Codename One - Maven Project in Eclipse unable to generate new class

Tags: java, maven, import, codenameone

I have a new Android project that I am trying to build with Maven.

I was able to download and import the project in Eclipse, but I am unable to generate a new class inside the the src directory.

The warning I get from File -> New -> Class is : Source folder is not a Java project.

I found a couple of solutions on the internet, saying that it is necessary to include Java from the project facets, but there is no Java option on the tab.

Any solution to this? I am working on Arch Linux.

[image]

[image]

Comment: In which folder are you trying to create a new class/package?
`common/src/main` should be the root for the sources.

Comment: Hi, @ShaiAlmog, thanks for looking into this. I am using this folder. Have a added a screenshot.

Comment: I got it sorted out. The solution was adding the Maven Java EE plugin from the Eclipse Marketplace.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is adding the Maven Java EE plugin to Eclipse. I found this by typing "facets" in the Market Place search field. This plugin came up and I gave it a go. Luckily, it worked.

[image]

After this, you can find several options in project facets. Choose Java :

Properties -> Project Facets -> Java

This site here pointed me into the right direction and explains the process in more detail: [Source Folder is not a Java Project](https://javahungry.blogspot.com/2019/04/source-folder-is-not-a-java-project-error-in-eclipse.html)

[image]